# Displaying date in meteor

Tags: javascript, html, date, templates, meteor

I'm currently learning the meteor framework, and right now I can't quite understand why my code isn't working. I'm attempting to create a template called "time" that has a variable called "current_time" which uses new Date(); to display the time on my HTML file, but it isn't working. As you can see my goal below is to display an array of images, and then the time, but all it shows is "the time now is" without showing the time.

Here's my HTML and JS file (I tried to make it following the same logic for the first template images which my course uses):

```
<head>
      <title>Welcome to My social media app... kind of.</title>
    </head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello from America!</h1>
  <div class="container">
  {{> images}}
  {{> time}}
 </div>

</body>

<template name="images">
    <div class="row">
   {{#each images}}
    <div class ="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
    <img class="js-image" src="{{img_src}}" alt="{{img_alt}}"/>

  <div class="caption">
     <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
    <p>Description of the image</p>
 </div>
   </div>
     </div> <!-- /col -->

   {{/each}}
   </div> <!-- / row -->
   </template>

   <template name="time">
         <p>The time now is: {{current_time}}</p>
  </template>

    if (Meteor.isClient) {
       var img_data = [
      {
        img_src:"alley.JPG",
         img_alt:"Alley in town"
       },
      ];

      Template.images.helpers({images: img_data});

      Template.images.events({
        'click .js-image':function(event) {
          $(event.target).css("width", "50px");
       }
      });

      var current_time = new Date();

     Template.time.helpers({time: current_time});
    }

    if (Meteor.isServer) {
        // code to run on server at startup
       console.log("I am the server");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your helper to:

```
Template.time.helpers({
  time: function(){ return new Date(); }
});
```

Comment: Was there a particular reason why declaring a variable and then putting it in the function didn't work?

Comment: Also, how would I call this in a template?

Comment: If you want to call this from any template then [register a helper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper). To your earlier question, helpers normally return functions which are then called by blaze. You were returning a static variable and it wasn't defined at the point the helper was *called*.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the links. I'll do my best to read through the documentation and figure it out. I was under the impression that it was going to just be a simple matter of creating a global variable within the "isClient" brackets and then putting the name of that variable with a name within a template helper with the same name as the template I create, but I guess I'm missing something. I'll keep plugging along.

Comment: You created a helper for a specific template. If you want one for all templates then you want the other style.

Comment: Actually my goal was just to create one for a single template= "time"

Comment: I think if you'd do time() { return current_time } inside that helper it would work, you were missing the syntax for how to declare a helper and a return inside of it so it was calling what you did but wasn't displaying it in the template